# How to get the dimensions of Base64-encoded image in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a REST API return a Base64-encoded image:

[API response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ECNL.jpg)

Is there a way to get dimensions (height, width) of this image?

Comment: This is the subject of [a meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422857/how-can-we-link-together-these-web-api-question-posts-about-getting-the-dimensio).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an [`Image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) object with the given `src` and directly access the `width` and `height` properties.

```js
let url = 'data:image/png;base64,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';
// same image as https://via.placeholder.com/50x50
let img = new Image();
img.src = url;
img.onload = function() {
  console.log(img.width, img.height);
}
document.body.append(img); // just for demonstration
```